# Python Speech Recognition listen_in_background on button press?

Tags: python, google-speech-api

Currently I'm trying to have the speech_recognition module listen in the background when the user pushes a button made with py qt. I have the initialization and callback methods in a class, however when I try and listen to the microphone it doesn't seem to be registering anything, not even outputting errors.

```
class VoiceRecognitionWidget(ScriptedLoadableModuleWidget):
    def callback(self, recognizer, audio):
        try: 
          print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
        # handles any api/voice errors  errors 
        except sr.RequestError: 
          print( "There was an issue in handling the request, please try again")
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
          print("Unable to Recognize speech")

    def onApplyButton(self):
        #self.displayLabel.setText("Listening for speech....")

        self.recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        try: 
          self.microphone = sr.Microphone()

        except(IOError):
          print("ERROR: No default microphone. Check if microphone is plugged in or if you have a default microphone set in your sound settings.")
          self.errors.setText("ERROR: No default microphone. Check if your microphone is plugged in or if you have a default microphone set in your sound settings.")

        with self.microphone as source:
          self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
          # audio = self.recognizer.listen(source)

        stop_listening = self.recognizer.listen_in_background(self.microphone, self.callback)
```

The microphone works when I just listen to it normally when I press the button, it's just that when I try to have it continuously listen it doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried creating the recognizer and microphone in a function in the same class that initializes the whole GUI (not shown) but that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On callback function I put `self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio)` regardless the `recognizer` parameter. For sure, the class need to have a `recognizer = sr.Recognizer()`